# google chrome extension messaging background to context

Tags: google-chrome-extension, messaging

I am writing an extension for Google Chrome.  The content script never sees that sendNextProfile request has been sent from background page.  At least, the message RECEIVED REQUEST FOR NEXT PROFILE never appears on the console log and no new request is seen by background.

HERE IS THE CODE FROM THE CONTENT SCRIPT

```
//send request for first profile
var currentProfile=0;
chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "openProfile", url: profileLinks[currentProfile]});

//listen for request to send next profile
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.cmd == "sendNextProfile") {
        console.log("RECEIVED REQUEST FOR NEXT PROFILE");
        ++currentProfile;
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "openProfile", url: profileLinks[currentProfile]});
    }
});
```

HERE IS THE CODE FROM THE BACKGROUND PAGE

```
//detect when message tab is closed and request new profile
//var closedTabId=null;
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabid, removeInfo) { 
    console.log("TAB CLOSED "+tabid);
    if (tabid==msgTabId) {
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "sendNextProfile"});
        console.log("REQUESTED NEW PROFILE");
    }   
});
```

On the background side, the console message appear as expected, so it appears the request is send.  So what's up with this code?

Comment: `On the background side, the console message appear as expected.`

what message appears exactly? TAB CLOSED or REQUESTED NEW PROFILE or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "sendNextProfile"});
```

it should be:

```
chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tabId, {cmd: "sendNextProfile"});
```

But if your tab is removed there is no point in sending request to that tab as it doesn't exist already. Maybe you need to send it to some other tab?

Comment: actually the search page should still be open.  but the background didn't open it so background doesn't yet learned the tabid for the search page.  the misunderstanding here is the idea that the message is directed to a tab and not broadcast for any tab to hear.  but having thought about it, the better approach would be to send the whole array of search results to background and let background control the processing as there is no need for the search page to do anything more than to collect the links into an array.