# chrome google extension send message data from background to ui

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, plugins

I have read several forums [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177463/chrome-extension-send-message-from-background-to-background) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401564/google-chrome-extension-messaging-background-to-context), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293160/chrome-extension-tabs-sendmessage-from-background-to-contentscript-errors) but didn't solve my issue.
On load, I need to pass the data from background.js (coming from an api response) to my content script so that It would populate my dropdown menu. I have tried several codes but nothing worked. It doesn't have error, just that nothing happens.

the following commented and un-commented codes inside `sendTocontent`  are what I have tried in background.js. Pls note that if I use the tabs[0].id - this is empty array or sometimes not defined so I had to work around for the lasttabid - I figured this must be the issue but how ??? That's all I see in the documentation.

background.js

```
 var lastTabId = -1;

function sendMessage() {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    lastTabId = tabs[0].id;
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(lastTabId, "Background page started.");
  });
}
sendMessage();
let uri=chrome.runtime.getURL('');
chrome.storage.local.set({ "chrome_uri" :uri })


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
  var environment = "http://localhost:9126/";

    $.ajax({
      url: environment + "Plugin/list",
      type:'get',
       success:function(data){
         var profiles = JSON.parse(data.Content);
         sendTocontent(profiles);
       }
    })



});


function sendTocontent(somedata){
  
  //  chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true},
  //   function(tabs) {
  //     chrome.tabs.sendMessage( tabs[0].id, {sender:'background', somedata:somedata});
  //   })
  // chrome.extension.sendMessage({somedata: "hello"}, function(response) {
  //   console.log(response);
  // });
  //   chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
  //     chrome.tabs.sendMessage(lastTabId, {action: "open_dialog_box"}, function(response) {});  
  // });

  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(
    lastTabId,
    {'profileList': true});
}
```

this is my contentscript called `toolbar.js:`

```
//i tried this
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
    if (request.sender=='background') {
      alert("Request sent sucesss")
    }
  });
//i tried this
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(

  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
  } 
);

function onExtensionMessage(request) {
  if (request['profileList'] != undefined) {
    alert("onExtensionMessage")
  } 
}
//i tried this
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onExtensionMessage);
```

excerpt from my manifest:

```
"background" : {
   "scripts" : ["js/jquery.js","background.js"]
 },
"content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": ["*://*/*"],
    "js": ["js/jquery.js","js/toolbar.js"],
    "css": ["button.css"]
    }
  ],
permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "tabs"],
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is actually trivial.

1. The **content script** sends a message to the background script.

   ```js
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'getProfiles'}, profiles => {
     console.log(profiles);
     //useProfiles(profiles);
   });
   ```
2. The **background script** fetches the URL and responds with the result.

   ```js
   chrome.runtime.onMessage((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
     if (msg.action === 'getProfiles') {
       fetch('http://localhost:9126/Plugin/list')
         .then(r => r.json())
         .then(json => sendResponse(json.Content));
       // keep the channel open for sendResponse while `fetch` runs asynchronously
       return true;
     }
   });
   ```

Yep, this is the entire code.